# How to generate description and keywords metatags in Doxygen HTML output?

Tags: seo, doxygen

For better SEO, I'd like to generate the "description" and "keywords" metatags in the HTML output produced by Doxygen. I've noticed that these metatags are present in the [original Doxygen HTML documentation](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html). But I cannot figure out how to supply these metatags in my own projects. Also, I'd like to use *different* metatags in different HTML pages (the Doxygen documentation merely repeats the same metatags in all HTML pages.)

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What meta tags are you talking about? The header is supplied either as build in html header or a header file (one for the whole project) as provided by the setting `HTML_HEADER`. Please show exactly what you mean.

Comment: I mean the following metatags:
<meta name="description" content="Source code documentation and analysis tool"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="documentation,tool,source code,open source,GPL,analysis,structure"/>

Comment: Normally these tags are not added to the documentation, but these 2 are added to the documentation just for the website (even in te documentation as distributed I don't see them). As implied in the previous comment you can define your own header and add here these tags (have a look at e.g `doxygen --help` and especially at `doxygen -l html ...` and the relevant tags etc. in the documentation.